# Working with indexes - is this normal behavior?

Tags: mysql

I have a roughly 4gb database with most data stored in a single table - it currently has over 34 million entries with 8 datapoints each and two indexes;

```
CREATE TABLE `cdr_records` (
  `dateTimeOrigination` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `callingPartyNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `originalCalledPartyNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finalCalledPartyNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pkid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `origDeviceName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `destDeviceName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkid`),
  KEY `tableIndex` (`dateTimeOrigination`,`callingPartyNumber`,`originalCalledPartyNumber`,`finalCalledPartyNumber`),
  KEY `webPageIndex1` (`callingPartyNumber`,`originalCalledPartyNumber`,`finalCalledPartyNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

A query can take one of two forms;

1) Show me all entries for a value.  This value can be in 'callingPartyNumber', originalCalledPartNumber', or 'finalCalledPartyNumber'.

```
select 
    from_unixtime(dateTimeOrigination) as date_of_call_origination,
    callingPartyNumber as calling_party_number, 
    originalcalledpartynumber as original_called_party_number,
    finalCalledPartyNumber as final_called_party_number, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(duration) as duration, 
    origDeviceName, 
    destDeviceName from cdr_records
  where 
    (callingPartyNumber=? or originalcalledpartynumber=? or finalcalledpartynumber=?)
  order by datetimeorigination desc;
```

2) Show me all entries for a value between two given dates in 'dateTimeOrigination'.  This value can be in 'callingPartyNumber', originalCalledPartNumber', or 'finalCalledPartyNumber'.  For example;

```
select 
    from_unixtime(dateTimeOrigination) as date_of_call_origination,
    callingPartyNumber as calling_party_number, 
    originalcalledpartynumber as original_called_party_number,
    finalCalledPartyNumber as final_called_party_number, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(duration) as duration, 
    origDeviceName, 
    destDeviceName from cdr_records
  where 
    (callingPartyNumber=? or originalcalledpartynumber=? or finalcalledpartynumber=?)
  and from_unixtime(dateTimeOrigination)
                      between         '2017-01-24'
                          and ADDDATE('2017-01-25', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  order by datetimeorigination desc;
```

When I run an explain on either query, they match with the 'webPageIndex1' index.  At this point, any query I run takes about 48 seconds.

So, a couple of question;

1) I would have thought that the second type of query would match with the 'tableIndex' index instead of 'webPageIndex1' as it specifies beginning and end dates - am I seeing this wrong (the first query does match with 'webPageIndex1')?

2) 48 seconds seems like a long time for an indexed search.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Updates to indexes and statement optimization suggestions;

    CREATE TABLE `cdr_records` (
      `dateTimeOrigination` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `callingPartyNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `originalCalledPartyNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `finalCalledPartyNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `pkid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `origDeviceName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `destDeviceName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`pkid`),
      KEY `tableIndex` (`dateTimeOrigination`,`callingPartyNumber`,`originalCalledPartyNumber`,`finalCalledPartyNumber`),
      KEY `callingPartyNumberIndex` (`callingPartyNumber`,`dateTimeOrigination`),
      KEY `originalCalledPartyNumberIndex` (`originalCalledPartyNumber`,`dateTimeOrigination`),
      KEY `finalCalledPartyNumberIndex` (`finalCalledPartyNumber`,`dateTimeOrigination`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here statement tested;

```sql
(
    select from_unixtime(dateTimeOrigination) as date_of_call_origination ,
        callingPartyNumber as calling_party_number,
        originalcalledpartynumber as original_called_party_number,
        finalCalledPartyNumber as final_called_party_number,
        SEC_TO_TIME(duration) as duration,
        origDeviceName, destDeviceName
    from cdr_records
    where callingPartyNumber='?'
)
union distinct (
    select from_unixtime(dateTimeOrigination) as date_of_call_origination ,
        callingPartyNumber as calling_party_number,
        originalcalledpartynumber as original_called_party_number,
        finalCalledPartyNumber as final_called_party_number,
        SEC_TO_TIME(duration) as duration,
        origDeviceName, destDeviceName
    from cdr_records
    where originalcalledpartynumber='?'
)
union distinct (
    select from_unixtime(dateTimeOrigination) as date_of_call_origination ,
        callingPartyNumber as calling_party_number,
        originalcalledpartynumber as original_called_party_number,
        finalCalledPartyNumber as final_called_party_number,
        SEC_TO_TIME(duration) as duration,
        origDeviceName, destDeviceName
    from cdr_records
    where finalcalledpartynumber='?'
)
```

New update;

```
explain select from_unixtime(dateTimeOrigination), callingPartyNumber, originalCalledPartyNumber, finalCalledPartyNumber, SEC_TO_TIME(duration), origDeviceName, destDeviceName from cdr_records where (callingPartyNumber='?' or originalCalledPartyNumber='?' or finalCalledPartyNumber='?') and from_unixtime(dateTimeOrigination) between '2017-02-01' and ADDDATE('2017-02-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY) order by dateTimeOrigination desc;
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type        | possible_keys                                                                      | key                                                                                | key_len  | ref  | rows    | Extra                                                                                                                             |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cdr_records | index_merge | callingPartyNumberIndex,originalCalledPartyNumberIndex,finalCalledPartyNumberIndex | callingPartyNumberIndex,originalCalledPartyNumberIndex,finalCalledPartyNumberIndex | 53,53,53 | NULL | 2212197 | Using sort_union(callingPartyNumberIndex,originalCalledPartyNumberIndex,finalCalledPartyNumberIndex); Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
```

Update

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache%';
+------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                | Value    |
+------------------------------+----------+
| query_cache_limit            | 1048576  |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096     |
| query_cache_size             | 16777216 |
| query_cache_type             | ON       |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF      |
+------------------------------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Update
mysql> show session status like 'Handler%';

```
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 0     |
| Handler_read_key           | 12196 |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 15251 |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 12193 |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 0     |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 0     |
+----------------------------+-------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` and `Handlers` are for `OR`.  Were you going to try them with `UNION`?

Comment: Are there really 15K (or more) rows with the '?' number you are testing with?  If so, the performance won't get better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OR` can often be optimized by using `UNION`:

```
( SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE callingPartyNumber = ? )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE originalcalledpartynumber = ? )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE finalcalledpartynumber = ? )
```

And have 3 separate indexes, one per `SELECT`:

```
INDEX(callingPartyNumber,       dateTimeOrigination)
INDEX(originalcalledpartynumber,dateTimeOrigination)
INDEX(finalcalledpartynumber,   dateTimeOrigination)
```

Your composite indexes are useful only if you have all those columns in the `WHERE` and they are connected with `AND`, not `OR.

Those 3 indexes will work equally well for both of your queries (after the further hint, below).

Don't hide columns in function calls:

```
from_unixtime(dateTimeOrigination) between ...
```

Instead

```
dateTimeOrigination BETWEEN unix_timestamp(...) AND unix_timestamp(...)
```

**More debugging**

Run this:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

This will help us diagnose whether the query is hitting more rows than "it ought to".

**UNION vs Index merge**

One of the `EXPLAINs` shows "Index merge".  This is rarely used, but when it is used for `OR`, it will (probably) be better than using the `UNION` that I am recommended.  So...  Do the `EXPLAIN`, if it does not say "Index merge" (and multiple numbers in Key_len), then use `UNION`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53296/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-working-with-indexes-is-this-normal-behavio).